# Do not autoresize UILabel

Tags: cocoa-touch, uilabel, adjustment

everybody, this is my question:

i have a UILabel that displays the hour with seconds in the format HH:mm:ss.
But, the content of the label always move to the right when the seconds are: '01' because the number 1 is "smaller" than the width of the number 9.

i had unchecked "Adjust to fit" in IB and setAdjustsFontSizeToWidth:NO but that did not solve the problem.

I think the answer is there in IB but anything seems to work.

Any idea ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this which is inherited from `UIView`:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL autoresizesSubviews
```

and set it to false, if you just don't want the `UILabel` to autoresize.